# [Error: TransformError SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

Practicing programming with React-Native, and found this problem which I did not know how to solve.
Had try to use solutions from other forums, did not work.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import Logo from '../../assets/images/possible.jpg';

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Image source={Logo} style={styles.logo} resizeMode='contain' />
    </View>
  )
}
```

I've never used typescript before, not sure is it something with ts?

Comment: By `import` do you mean `export`?

Comment: You have `import` in line 3, but don't import anything.

Comment: ahhh, let me correct it, I mis-typed it.
I mean, the simulator still works, but the terminal keep popping up issues.

Comment: I understand you're minimising the amount of code you put in the question, however, you're probably not showing enough to determine the error ... for example, what even is `styles.logo`?

Comment: NVM, I think I fixed the problem, somehow

Answer (score 0):

I think I lost the `import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'`,
after importing back this into the file, it's not yelling at me somehow!

I looked up in https://reactnative.dev/docs/stylesheet , and added it, or maybe I'm just tripping

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).